# Breakpoints set but not yet bound in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Running Visual Studio Community 2017. Created a WebAPI project, have a controller class in there, with some basic stuff, but when I go to run in debug mode, I get the following error on my breakpoints, and I haven't the foggiest idea why.

`The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoints set but not yet bound.`

I've seen a few answers here and there, but they don't help, or they're about Visual Studio Code, which I am definitely not using.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/binding-breakpoints), but it doesn't tell me what to do about my problem. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Have u tried to clean the solution. You have a dropdown in VS where has some values like `Debug`, `Release` etc, dont forget to set that as `Debug` mode. Is your application hosted in IIS or just running from VS directly ?

Comment: You should also cleanup you bin and obj folders

Comment: I'm running from Visual Studio directly. I'm also in `Debug` for sure. Clean the solution didn't work. I'm especially puzzled since the project is new, even though the rest of the solution isn't.

Comment: How many projects in your solution?

Comment: The WebAPI project I just added makes for a total of 9.

Comment: Still happening in VS 2019

Comment: This is still occurring on Visual Studio 2022 on my .NET Framework web application.  I tried every answer/suggestion on this page and none of it worked for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting your web project as default [Startup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx).

Comment: Or, in my case, remember to add your new web-service project to the list of multiple Startup projects for your solution!

Answer (score 51):

Change your Project mode from Release to Debug in your Visual Studio.

[image: Debug Mode]

Comment: For whatever reason, I had to (or ended up) setting all the other (non-startup) projects in my solution to be have debug configuration also. Once I did this, I was able to add a breakpoint that worked. Not sure how I got into this state, I had not updated Visual Studio in over a week and didn’t have this issue until today.
Previously (today), I had done the clean/rebuild and deleted all my breakpoints. Neither of which worked. And my startup project was already set debug configuration. I even updated to the latest VS version able (VS Prof. 2019 ver: 16.3.10) and that didn’t help either.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Multiple projects, you need to make sure the step below, let project debug normally

1. Confirm the project which you want to debug is a default project, otherwise setting it as `startup project` [image]
2. Confirm your project mode is `Debug` instead of `Release`[image]
3. `Clean` your solution or projects  and rebuild your projects [image]
4. Restart & Running your Current project.

Answer (score 4):

Just clear the solution and re-start Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Clean the solution:

Build -> Clean [solution name]

Answer (score 2):

This helped me

1). Build > Clean Solution and then restart Visual Studio and rebuild your project, after that debug again.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/265772/visual-studio-debugging-breakpoint-set-but-yet-bou.html

Comment: Thanks for linking to the source of your information. Consider also copying the the other steps (2. and 3.) and maybe naming the author there. You can explain that only the first step was needed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

1.Clean the Solution
2.Set Startup Project
3.Restart the Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Usually it can happen even if all the configurations in project are OK, so do the following.

Right Click to **Solution** and under **Configuration** change **Release** to **Debug**

[image]

Comment: Several other answers suggest switching from Release to Debug including [this one from Sandeep Kumar Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905415/3744182) and [this one from D-Shih](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845337/3744182) and [this one from Deekshith Shekar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043462/3744182).  Might you please [edit] your question and add some explanation that explains how your answer extends beyond those?

Comment: Because it provides a quick overview of all the projects in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following steps to troubleshoot:

1). Build > Clean Solution and then restart Visual Studio and rebuild your project, after that debug again.

2). Please go to your solution folder and delete(or rename) the “obj”, “bin” and the hidden “.vs” folder, restart Visual Studio and then rebuild your solution.

3). Check if you have chosen the “Debug” mode and if you have many other projects in this solution, make sure you have set the “Set as Startup Project” for the corresponding project.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/265772/visual-studio-debugging-breakpoint-set-but-yet-bou.html)

Comment: At the time I encountered this problem I solved it from that answer. And for ease and simplicity I brought it here on stack overflow. I should have to mention the source though. Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same message even though I tried most of the suggestions here. What worked in the end was to change the "Project Url" under "Properties" of the website project. In my scenario I changed it from `http://localhost/productname.web` to `http://localhost:56260`.

Answer (score 1):

If your breakpoint is in a different project and only this one is not reachable, check if "Enable Just My Code" is activated under Tools > Options > Debugging > General.

Answer (score 0):

**Select Debug instead of Release...And it might work..**

[image: Open this link to see the step]

Comment: Already answered three years prior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905415/215552

Answer (score 0):

If your Web API project is running in IIS, and / or was launched on a terminal (e.g. if you are using .net Core), and that you are in a case that you need to attach the debugger to an already running process, make sure Visual Studio was run as an administrator, unless it won't be allowed to attach to the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a typo in your Javascript, the breakpoint will not work.  I used "<>" instead of "!=" and when I fixed it, the breakpoint worked again.

Comment: I use C# as part of my .net application and use JavaScript for the front end. I encountered this exact message, and it was happening on the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

"Break point will not be hit" warning will show, when you try to put a break point in "javascript" file while the solution is running .Solution to this is , stop debugging and put break point in the javascript and run the project again

Answer (score 0):

Did everything but the issue was there, got it resolved finally when I cleared the cache of browser and the temporary ASP .Net Files folder in Windows/Microsoft .NET/Framework and Framework64.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the top answers fail for you, restart computer, then run again in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

My team was able to resolve this issue today and I wanted to share the solution because it is unique from everything else I have read online.  I hope it helps someone out there.

Here's our situation for some context:  We have an ASP.NET solution in Visual Studio that has two projects:  one for the API and one for the website.  It's got a mix of jQuery, JavaScript, and C# code.  We were able to debug JavaScript & jQuery code, but NOT the C# code.  That is when we were getting the dreadful "Breakpoints set but not yet bound in Visual Studio" error.  To make a long story short, we had to update a web.config file to point to the correct localhost port on my machine instead of the server.

This is what we had to do to get it working:

1. Open an instance (we will call this "the first instance") of Visual Studio (we will call it VS from now on) with the **website** project set as the Startup Project.
2. Open a second instance of Visual Studio with the **API** project set
   as the Startup Project.  Click the Start button to open the web browser.  You may get a server error (I did) but that's okay.  Copy the full address in the address bar (for example http://localhost:12345/).
3. Back to the first instance of VS, we had to edit the web.config file for the website project to point to the address we copied above.  This value was in the configuration section under appSettings.  There was a key in there that looked like this once we changed it:

```
    <add key="WebAPI_Address" value="http://localhost:12345/" />
```

4. Once this information is saved, we had to Start the API project in the second instance of VS, and then go to the first instance of VS and Start the website project there.

I hope I didn't leave anything out.  One thing to note is, the website localhost address is different for us compared to the localhost address when the API project was launched.  One of our developers got the same port number for both.  To resolve that issue, he had to Start the API project using a different browser, and then he got a unique port number.  I don't know why, maybe it depends on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

On an ASP.NET web project, this message appeared when trying to set a breakpoint on a script that was apparently cached - the browser wasn't loading the updated version of the script (originally embedded in the HTML, then moved to a separate file).

Clearing the cache resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue when creating a custom web.config template on an ASP.NET MVC Application. Issue was inside the *.csproj, had to set the following PropertyGroup.

```html
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Your_Custom_Configuration|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

For ASP debugging:

1. Open Chrome/Edge
2. Go the URL of the startup project
3. Debug -> Attach to Process -> Search w3wp.exe -> click it and press the "Attach" button

Answer (score -1):

Need to set the Solution Configuration to Debug mode. If it is release mode, the breakpoints will not be hit

[image]

Comment: Already answered three years prior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905415/215552

Answer (score -1):

vs might be in release mode. just change it to debug mode

Comment: Already answered three years prior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905415/215552