# Breakpoint cannot be hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco7

I'm trying to debug my code in Visual Studio but my Breakpoint is not hit no matter what I add or where I add it. It's giving me this message

[image]

How do I go back to debug mode? It seems like it's loading a release version. But I don't know where to find this is visual studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breakpoints set but not yet bound in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845105/breakpoints-set-but-not-yet-bound-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Can you right click on the solution => select properties => select configuration properties and check if your start up project is in release or debug mode?

Comment: Based on my research, I find that it may be related to your code. Can you provide a code example in your question so that I can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the debug build, run the application as debug build. You can easily choose the release / debug version in the top bar besides the "Start" button in the dropdown menu.
[image: This is right below the menu bar.]

Comment: What kind of application do you develop? Windows forms? UWP? Something else? Have you changed something in your debug configuration? Also this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845105/breakpoints-set-but-not-yet-bound-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on your project and click 'Properties'
2. from the left opening and click 'Build'
3. and 'configuration' select  Debug

Fixed!

Comment: You should do ' Rebuild ' and  'Clean'  project.

Comment: Yes I already did a clean project then hit rebuild.. I also changed the Publish from Release to Debug but still no luck

Comment: As far as I understand, you get an error in the view part.Well, does it debug at class level?

Comment: No tried the class still the same can't debug anything

Comment: You can try it on class ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help because we're not on the same terms :/